# JavaFX RippleAnimation over a Button

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I want to create a `RippleAnimation`, so I made a circle and used `ScaleTransition` and put it in a `Button` using the method `setGraphic(..);`

---

**Sample Code:**

```
        final Circle circle = new Circle(3);
        circle.setFill(Color.color(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
        ScaleTransition scaleTransition = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(500), circle);
        scaleTransition.setToX(50f);
        scaleTransition.setToY(50f);
        scaleTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
        scaleTransition.setCycleCount(1);
        button.setGraphic(circle);
        button.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                scaleTransition.play();
            }
        });
...
```

but it gets over the `Button`:

[image]

How i can achieve that the circle doesn't get over the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use shape clipping:

```
Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
clip.widthProperty().bind(button.widthProperty());
clip.heightPropety().bind(button.heightProperty());

circle.setClip(clip);
```

Hope this works, cause haven't worked with `setGraphics()` ever. Maybe try putting button + circle into a `StackPane` to achieve same results.

Comment: scaleTransition makes the circle big but the shape doesn't changes to the clip(?)
(I can't explain it in English...)
so I used thread and made the circle's radius long. It worked, thank you!

Comment: By using a thread I hope you mean the `Timeline` class. Never use threads other than the FX Application Thread, to change a live scene.

Comment: Oh, `Timeline` is easier and more stable. Thanks!